# attr() not working on mobile safari

Tags: attr

Very new to jquery... I am trying to figure out why on mobile safari that my attr() is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var i= 0;
var winHeight= $(window).resize().height();

var iDivs= ['bgImage5','bgImage4','bgImage3','bgImage2','bgImage1'];
var currentPhoto= iDivs[i];

    $('div.bgImage').attr({id:currentPhoto})
    $('#bioBody').hide();
    $('#bio').click(function(){
    $('#bioBody').slideToggle('slow')
    });
<div id="imgContainer">
    <div></div>
    <div class="bgImage"></div>
    <div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be `$('.bgImage').attr('id', 'currentPhoto');`